# FQL query is not working

Tags: facebook-fql

I have a Facebook application which was working a year before (version 1.0 of the API). Now I am trying to make it work again but it seems the FQL query is not getting any data.

For instance I have this simple query:

```
try{
    $mailbox_email_num = $facebook->api(
        array(
            'method'=>'fql.query',
            'query'=>"SELECT total_count,unread_count FROM mailbox_folder WHERE viewer_id = xxxxx"
        )
    );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e){
    print_r ($e);
}
```

It works well through the online FQL editor and also before the updates of the API.

Now, I get an error code 606 -- "Wrong number of arguments passed into the function"(http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html) while I am running the application.

Does anyone know why and how it can be solved?

Do I need to mention somewhere the version of the API that I want to use?

Comment: "it´s not working" and "it doesn´t do anything" are not sufficient error descriptions. FQL is deprecated and will not work in new apps anymore (v2.1). you can only use it in old apps created before v2.1 was published), there is no downgrade.

Comment: What version of the API and SDK are you using? I've never seen that 606 error before - are you sure you're not accidentally hitting api.facebook.com instead of graph.facebook.com? that wiki is from 2011, by the way - the API has been more or less completely replaced since then

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors that Facebook placed under the 606 code. This particular one is most likely

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#606) You can only fetch messages for one user", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 606
  }
}
```

You are probably using an id in the viewer_id column for which you don't have access for.